# Export Users from User Pool in aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, export, amazon-cognito

I am trying to export users' data in the user pool. Is there any option providing AWS Cognito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, Cognito does not allow a way to export users from a user pool

You can write a lambda to export your Cognito user data, but not password. (Ref https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/migrating-users-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools/)

We asked AWS support this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Once you can do a migration to the userpool, you can do the same to migrate it outside of it, but you need to implement whole migration yourself. It will not be atomic migration, but migrating only user which is just loging in.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. `cognito-export-users` NPM package

The `cognito-export-users` NPM package is a great option for exporting Cognito user data:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-export-users/v/2.0.0

Usage is simple:

`cognito-export-users <user_pool_id>`

## 2. AWS CLI

You can also simply use the AWS CLI:

`aws --region us-east-1 cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id <user_pool_id> --profile <credential_profile_name> --output json > cognito-users.json`

(see [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) for information on authenticating to AWS with a credential profile)